# How to change react component on someone else's onclick

Tags: html, reactjs

I am building a React app where I render a family tree. For that, in each of the family tree component nodes, I have added a onclick which opens a modal (aka popup form) that allows the user to edit the info of that person. In that modal/popup, I have a submit button on the bottom. I want it so that when the submit button is clicked, the input fields in the form (ex: name, parents, etc..) are fetched and updated on the respective node in the tree. I tried this in my code:

```
submitbtn.onclick = () => {
    alert("couple submit clicked!");
    info.husband = document.getElementById("hname_inp").value;
    info.wife = document.getElementById("wname_inp").value;
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    alert(info.husband + ' ' + info.wife)
  };
  return (
    <li>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>
        <span className="male">{info.husband}</span>
        <span className="spacer"></span>
        <span className="female">{info.wife}</span>
      </div>
      <Children />
    </li>
  );
```

By default, the component shows the info passed through props. When the submit button is clicked, i want the data from the input fields to replace the data in the component. The onclick and the data is feteched fine, but the component is not updated. I am new to React so it might just be a silly mistake, please bare with me.
Finally, and this is a little of the topic, but when I click the submit button, the screen flickers for a second a html page with no formatting shows up then it goes back to normal. What might be the cause for that?

Edit (New Code):

```
import React from "react";

export default class Couple extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      husband: this.props.husband,
      wife: this.props.wife,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const newState = this.state
    const modal = document.getElementById('coupleModal');
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    const submitbtn = document.getElementById('couplesubmitbtn');
    submitbtn.onClick = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      modal.style.display = 'none'
      newState.husband = document.getElementById('hname').value;
      newState.wife = document.getElementById('wname').value;
    }
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    const children = this.props.children;
    return (
      <li>
        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <span className="male">{this.state.husband}</span>
          <span className="spacer"></span>
          <span className="female">{this.state.wife}</span>
        </div>
        {children != null && children.length !== 0 ? <ul>{children}</ul> : ""}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do  you have a reprodicble fiddle or codesandbox?

Comment: No, I am making this locally on my machine. If you want, I can create  a github repo and push my project there?

Comment: yeah an reprodcible scenario would be good.

Comment: Ok I have added my code to github. When I try to deploy it using gh-pages, something doesn't work and the whole thing crashes but it works locally in my machine (but with the flickering i mentioned earlier) here is the repo: https://github.com/AyushKool/FamilyTreeApp/tree/master

Comment: Also, i tried to deploy my app again and it still looks like this: https://ayushkool.github.io/FamilyTreeApp/ and this is what the react page looks like when it flickers in my machine. The only difference is, in my machine, it flickers and goes back to normal (without changing the state as stated in the prev. comment) and in the deployed website, the whole app just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments before it would be great if you could provide a fiddle etc to look at.

You mentioned that you are new to React so even at the risk of sounding stupid may I just ask are you using some sorf of state handling here? If not then it might be something to look into. If you're already familiar with React state this answer is pointless and should be ignored.

In reactjs.org there are great documentations about what is the difference between state and props?

> setState() schedules an update to a component’s state object. When state changes, the component responds by re-rendering.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props

So in this case information about your family tree would be initialized to state and popup should then update the state via setState. The new input then gets update and UI components rerender.

If I'm right and the state handling will help you go forward I would also recommend to look up React Hooks. Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8 and when you grasp an idea of state using Hooks will be a easy and more elegant way to write your application

====================  **Part 2**  ====================

Here's the answer to your question you asked below in comments and some additional thoughts:

I assume the flickering is actually page refreshing on submit. So catching the user event and passing it on and calling preventDefault() is a way to go. I will an example below.

Looking at your code I'm more and more convinced that you are indeed lacking the state handling and it's the initial problem here. You could really benefit reading little bit more about it. At the same time it will help you understand better the logic of how React generally works.

Here's another link that might be worth checking out:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781/

And lastly here's the codeSnippet. Note that the wifes input element you're trying to target with `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById("hname")` instead of `document.getElementById("hname_inp")`

```
submitbtn.onclick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(props.wife);
  modal.style.display = "none";
  info.husband = document.getElementById("name").value;
  info.wife = document.getElementById("hname").value;
  alert(info.husband + " " + info.wife);
};
```

====================  **Part 3**  ====================

Nice to see that you took a closer look on state handling and have tried it out. I would continue building the knowledge with some additional reading. Here's a good post about Reacts Data handling.

https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf

So instead of using state handling separately in different components I would suggest that you move it to App.js as it is the obvious Parent component of others. There you should also think about the data structure. I assume this project is not going to be connected (at least for now) for any api or database and so it's something that would be handled here as well.

So defining some sort of baseline to App.js could look for example like this.

```
this.state = {
  state = { family : [
      [{ name: 'kari', gender: male }]
      [
        { name: 'jasper', gender: male },
        { name: 'tove', gender: femmale }
      ],
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I suggest that you move the handlers here as well. Then writing them here you don't maybe even need separate ones to couples and singles any more.

I'm sorry to hear your still seeing the flickering. My best guess for this is that modal isn't aware about the event.preventDefault. For clarity I would refactor this a bit as well. Generally it's not a good practice to try to modify things via getElements inside React. It's usually all state and props all the way. So I added a few lines of code here as an example of how you could continue on

```
import React from "react";
import SingleModal from "./Modals/SingleModal";

export default class Couple extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    };
    this.popUpHandler = this.popUpHandler.bind(this);
  }

  popUpHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible})
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <>
        <SingleModal visible={this.state.visible} popUpHandler={this.popUpHandler }/>
        <li>
          <div onClick={this.popUpHandler}>
            <span className={this.props.gender}>{this.props.name}</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And similary in SingleModal getting rid of the form submit like this:

```
<input
type="submit"
value="Submit"
className="submit"
id="singlesubmitbtn"
onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.popUpHandler(e)
}}
/>
```

PS. I think this is going to be my last answer on this question here. The answer is getting too long and it's starting to drift off topic of the original question. Good luck with your project

Comment: thanks, I will give that a try. Also, as I mentioned before, I have some issues with the webpage flickering after clicking submit button. And when i deploy the app to github pages, the react webpage doesn't come up at all. I think that it might be because the modal/popup I created is outside of the root div that the reactdom uses to render stuff and i am trying to get the input from the modal by react components. I have posted the github link in the comments of my question. Can you please see if that is the case, and if so, how should i fix it?

Comment: Sure. I will take a look.

Comment: @AyushKoul My answer was bit long to add here as comment so instead I edited my original answer. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, so if you go to my github repo in master, you will see that I fixed all the issues with state and now it changes when I change the state. The issue now is, the page still flickers when i click the submit button and the state doesnt change when i click the btn (it changes if I do anything else).

Comment: I have edited my question and added my new code of Couple.js if you want to look there (it is also updated in github master branch)

Comment: i tried to deploy this app, and the page doesn't load at all. instead, there is a plain html page with no styles being rendered. This is also the page that flickers when I run the app locally using npm start but in this case it quickly comes back to normal (except it doesn't change the state with the input values in the modal)

Comment: the deployed paged is here: https://ayushkool.github.io/FamilyTreeApp/
As you can see, the react components aren't rendered at all. And, as mentioned in the prev. comment, this is what the flickering page looks like when i run it but it then turns back to normal (but still doesn't update state)

Comment: @AyushKoul Added few more thoughts to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use different onClick functions on every node.and plus you can change name of the husband using a modal.I have used prompt and saved the data in state for husband and wife

```
const [Husband, setHusband] = useState("Varun")
const [Wife, setWife] = useState("Alia")
 const handleClick = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault()
setHusband(prompt("Please enter your Husband Name:"))
  };
 const handleWife = (e)=>{
     e.preventDefault()
     setWife(prompt("Please enter your Wife Name:"))
 }
return (
  <li>
    <div>
      <span className="male" onClick={handleClick}>{Husband}</span>
      <span className="spacer"></span>
      <span className="female" onClick={handleWife}>{Wife}</span>
    </div>
  </li>
);
};
```

Comment: Hi, your method is fine but it won't work in my case because I dont want to use a prompt I want to use a modal because I will be implementing many inputs that it is better if it is in a modal. My issue right now is, the submit button's onClick in not working for some reason. Instead, when i click submit, the page flickers and then comes back to normal. If you see my new code in my question, you will see what I am doing. The whole code is at  github.com/AyushKool/FamilyTreeApp/tree/master